# Xslt: <xsl:value-of select="MyPath/$MyVariable" failed

Tags: xslt, value-of

```
<xsl:value-of select="$MyVar"/>
```

works but

```
<xsl:value-of select="MyDataPfath/$MyVar"/>
```

do not work.

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you share your XML schema / example? Are you sure your node name is `MyDataPfath`?

Comment: What does `$MyVar` store - presumably the name of node?

Comment: I am sorry, i am newbie. Of course I have to explain the context.

Comment: I have a xml source file with `<foo><bar><value1>Hello 1</value1><value2>Hello abc</value2></bar></foo>`

Comment: I have another type of xml source file with encapsulated <foo><foo><bar><value1>first value in first sub foo</value1><value2>second @Utkanos value in first foo</value2></bar></foo> <foo><bar><value1>first value in second sub foo</value1><value2>second value in second sub foo</value2></bar></foo></foo>` And yes "foo" ist in the first hierachy and in the second hierachy level again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the look of it, what you are trying to achieve is 'dynamic evaluation'. XSLT does not support the dynamic evaluation of XPath by default, so you will need to make use of an extension function.

Depending on your XSLT processor, you might want to look at EXSLT extensions. In particular the **dynamic** module at http://www.exslt.org/dyn/index.html. This would allow to do something like this

```
<xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate('MyDataPfath/$MyVar')"/>
```

However, in your case, perhaps the $MyVar contains just a single element name. In which case you could change your command to the following, which would work without any extension functions

```
<xsl:value-of select="MyDataPfath/*[local-name() = $MyVar]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't fail, it did exactly what the specification says it should do. Which was different from what you were hoping/imagining that it might do.

Your hopes/imagination were based on a fundamental misunderstanding of the nature of variables in XPath. XPath variables are not macros. They don't work by textual substitution; they represent values. If the variable $E contains the string "X", then `MyPath/$E` means the same as `MyPath/"X"`, which is illegal in XPath 1.0, and in XPath 2.0 returns as many instances of the string "X" as there are nodes in MyPath.

You probably intended `MyPath/*[name()=$E]`

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to get the value by using syntax 'MyDataPfath/$MyVar' in . it will not recognize the proper path. 
suppose $MyVar has value 'Hi'. so it will be represented as 'MyDataPfath/"Hi"', this is not valid path, which you want to retrieve from the XML. 
to remove this limitation, You can use name() or local-name() function, that can be used as follows: 
  or